# How do I bring up the debug diagnostics tool windows while debugging my project in Visual Studio 2013 Professional?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

While all the other versions and editions of Visual Studio I use on different machines bring up the Diagnostics Tools windows when I launch any of my projects in the Visual Studio debugger by pressing F5, the Visual Studio 2013 Professional edition installation I have doesn't.

It does have the diagnostic tools, though.

How do I get it to start the debug session with diagnostics and to display the diagnostics windows as well automatically upon starting a debugging session?

Answer (score 0):

In VS2015, it has the option "Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->General.

But it doesn't have this feature in VS2013. It has the function Performance and Diagnostics hub under Debug menu.

It was the new feature in VS2015:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/07/20/performance-and-diagnostic-tools-in-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: @Water Cooler v2, would you please share the latest information about this issue?